# Value emit even if data isn't updated

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

I try yo use Room with Kotlin and RxJava 2.

I have an entity with a string primary key and I would like to be notified when values are updated but I receive new value from flowable even if the value isn't updated when I had whatever value.

Entity :

```
@Entity
class MarketSummaryModel(@PrimaryKey var marketName: String)...
```

Dao :

```
@Dao
interface MarketSummaryDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(marketSummaryModel: MarketSummaryModel)

@Query("select * from MarketSummaryModel where marketName = :marketName LIMIT 1")
fun getByName(marketName: String): Flowable<MarketSummaryModel>
}
```

Comment: You could try to work around this with `distinctUntilChanged()`...

Comment: I don't try because it's must be work without that. If I use a 'LiveData' I got the same bad behavior

Comment: Which version of the Architecture components do you use?

Comment: I use the 1.0.0-alpha9 version

Comment: This is a related issue with a solution: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215666/room-livedata-from-dao-will-trigger-observer-onchanged-on-every-update-even-i#