# Room LiveData observer (onChange) fired multiple times but only for INSERT

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-insert, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have noticed some strange behavior from the android Room library (at least it looks strange to me).

While there are other posts with **similar** problems, none of them (that I could find) are quite the same as this.

My issue is that when I observe a `LiveData` object, my observers' `onChange()` method is called multiple times but only for INSERT operation. The method will be triggered once for every object I insert (i.e. if I insert a list of N objects, it will be triggered N times), whereas for other operations (such as DELETE) it is fired once no matter the size of the list I am deleting.

I have the following queries in my DAO:

```
@query("select * from myTable")
LiveData<myEntity> getAll();

@insert
void insert(List<myEntity> entities);

@delete
void delete(List<myEntity> entities);
```

I am observing the `getAll()` method and I am definitely calling the `delete()` and `insert()` methods one time - something like this:

```
public void insertAll(List<myEntity> items)
{
    myDao.insert(items);
}
```

and

```
public void deleteAll(List<myEntity> items)
{
    myDao.delete(items);
}
```

Since in my `onChange()` method I am updating a `RecyclerView` adapter which is visible to the user, this is a problem as I am getting a lot of duplicates and also I am doing some other things in there which should really only be done once every time the table changes but instead they are executed many times (as I've said, once for every item inserted).

I have read this article and tried to implement tip number 7 but the problem persists.
https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1

Is this by design and considered normal behavior? What can I do to have my observer only fire once for every INSERT operation (even if I insert multiple objects at the same time)?

Comment: [See this link on StackOverflow with similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215666/room-livedata-from-dao-will-trigger-observer-onchanged-on-every-update-even-i/54120706#54120706) Maybe you did the same wrong, that I.

Comment: @zayn1991 thanks but i already solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while i don't fully understand it, i found the solution!

my problem was that i was calling `observe()` from `onNewIntent()` and that my call looks like this:

```
 mViewModel.getAll().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<MyObject>>()...);
```

the reason i was calling this from `onNewIntent()` is that this activity can be opened from almost anywhere in my app using the flag `BRING_TO_FRONT` (or whatever it's called) so `onCreate()` is not guaranteed to be called so i figured i better make sure that the observer is called by putting it in `onNewIntent()`.
i looked at the docs they say

> If the given owner, observer tuple is already in the list, the call is
>   ignored.

so i thought i was safe. what i failed to realize for some reason is that i am in fact creating a new observer every time with the `new` keyword. that with the combination of calling it from `onNewIntent()` lead to multiple **duplicate** observers which caused the `onChanged()` method to be triggered multiple times (well actually it was only called once, **but once per observer!**).

once i moved the `observe()` call to `onCreate()` the problem was fixed and i get a single call to `onChanged()` even when i insert multiple items to my table.

however this still does not explain how the `delete` method was only called once for multiple...