# StartActivityForResult called twice using Room, Coroutine and ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-viewmodel

I have problem when I come back in the activity from another.
In my activity I use a ViewModel and, when the activity is created I call `challengeDayViewModel.daysForChallenge` and I observe the changes. When data are ready I set them on the adapter. In the adapter when I click on item I call `challengeDayViewModel.getChallengeDay(dayId)` and observe for the result. When it is ready I start activity for result passing a property of the object retrieved. In the CountdownActivity I do some things and when I come back, in the `onActivityResult` method I update my data in DB using 
`challengeDayViewModel.setDayDone(selectedDayId)` and the problem is here. Commenting the row where I update the data in DB everything work perfectly but if I add the row for the update, the update is done but after he re-run the rown `startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequestCode.COUNTDOWN_CODE)` opening again the CountdownActivity (I see in debug)

```
class ChallengeDayActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private var selectedDayId: Long = 0
    private lateinit var adapter: ChallengeDayAdapter

    private val challengeDayViewModel: ChallengeDayViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application).create(ChallengeDayViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_challenge_day)

        val recyclerView = challenge_day_recyclerview
        adapter = ChallengeDayAdapter(this)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)

        challengeDayViewModel.daysForChallenge.observe(this, Observer { challengeDayList ->
            challengeDayList.let {
                adapter.setChallengeDay(challengeDayList)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })

        adapter.goToCountdown = { dayId ->
            selectedDayId = dayId
            challengeDayViewModel.getChallengeDay(dayId).observe(this, Observer { challengeDay ->
                val intent = Intent(this, CountdownActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("seconds", challengeDay.seconds)
                }

                startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequestCode.COUNTDOWN_CODE)
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == ActivityRequestCode.COUNTDOWN_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            challengeDayViewModel.setDayDone(selectedDayId)
            Snackbar.make(coordinator, "BUBU", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
}
```

My viewmodel is

```
class ChallengeDayViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val challengeDayRepository: ChallengeDayRepository

    val daysForChallenge: LiveData<List<ChallengeDay>>

    init {
        val challengeDayDao = database.challengeDayDao()

        challengeDayRepository = ChallengeDayRepository(challengeDayDao)

        daysForChallenge = challengeDayRepository.getChallengeDayForStandardChallenge()
    }

    fun setDayDone(challengeDayId: Long) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        challengeDayRepository.setDayDone(challengeDayId)
    }

    fun getChallengeDay(challengeDayId: Long): LiveData<ChallengeDay> = challengeDayRepository.getChallengeDay(challengeDayId)
}
```

My DAO

```
@Dao
interface ChallengeDayDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CHALLENGE_DAY WHERE CHD_ID_PK = :challengeDayId")
    fun getChallengeDay(challengeDayId: Long): LiveData<ChallengeDay>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CHALLENGE_DAY WHERE CHG_ID_FK = :challengeId")
    fun getChallengeDayForChallenge(challengeId: Long): LiveData<List<ChallengeDay>>

    @Query("SELECT CHD.* FROM CHALLENGE_DAY CHD JOIN CHALLENGE CHG ON CHD.CHG_ID_FK = CHG.CHG_ID_PK WHERE CHG.CHG_STANDARD = 1")
    fun getStandardChallengeDayForChallenge(): LiveData<List<ChallengeDay>>

    @Query("UPDATE CHALLENGE_DAY SET CHD_DONE = 1 WHERE CHD_ID_PK = :challengeDayId")
    suspend fun setDayDone(challengeDayId: Long)

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(challengeDay: ChallengeDay)

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(challengeDay: List<ChallengeDay>): List<Long>
}
```

In CountdownActivity for coming back I have this code

```
alert("Test message", "Test title") {
    okButton {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        finish()
    }
}.show()
```

Here the code for Repository

```
class ChallengeDayRepository(private val challengeDayDao: ChallengeDayDao) {

    @WorkerThread
    fun getChallengeDay(challengeDayId: Long): LiveData<ChallengeDay> = challengeDayDao.getChallengeDay(challengeDayId)

    @WorkerThread
    fun getAllChallengeDaysForChallenge(challengeId: Long): LiveData<List<ChallengeDay>> = challengeDayDao.getChallengeDayForChallenge(challengeId)

    @WorkerThread
    fun getChallengeDayForStandardChallenge(): LiveData<List<ChallengeDay>> = challengeDayDao.getStandardChallengeDayForChallenge()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun setDayDone(challengeDayId: Long) = challengeDayDao.setDayDone(challengeDayId)

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(challengeDay: ChallengeDay) = challengeDayDao.insert(challengeDay)

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insertAll(challengeDay: List<ChallengeDay>): List<Long> = challengeDayDao.insertAll(challengeDay)

}
```

Comment: probably you are updating two times 'getChallengeDay' liveData in 'ChallengeDayRepository', please also share code for 'ChallengeDayRepository', so we can understand and help you.

Comment: I added the code for ChallengeDayRepository

Answer (score 2):

Same question has already been asked in: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215666/room-livedata-from-dao-will-trigger-observer-onchanged-on-every-update-even-i)

Check answers in that post. 
One of solutions to prevent observe duplication, would be also to use SingleEvent LiveData: - source article can be found [here](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8), meaning that you consume data only once.

> ```
> open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {
>
>     var hasBeenHandled = false
>         private set
>
>     /**
>      * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
>      */
>     fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
>         return if (hasBeenHandled) {
>             null
>         } else {
>             hasBeenHandled = true
>             content
>         }
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
>      */
>     fun peekContent(): T = content
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350355/1937296) I write this that resolve my issue.

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, object: Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```